# C++: Parent object change their id attribute without method call

Tags: c++, class

As I specified in the title, this is a problem that puzzled me enormously, and still I can not find a fix for it.

I created a Point class which has three private attributes (_id, _x and _y) with related public get and set methods.
For example, I created three points (G, H, R), where the point G is a "parent". Point H is the prototype of the point G (a clone) and point R will be the outcome of the meeting points (G+H) (addition of the points).

**Points sample:**

```
    Point G ("pG", 3.5f, 6.5f);
    Point H (G.prototype ()); H.setId ("pH");
    Point R;
    R = G + H;
```

The program works correctly, but unfortunately after the operation {R=G+H}, _id attribute of point G becomes the clone attribute of point R, I do not understand why this is happening because the evaluation is done from right to left (H+, +G, =R).

The question is why G point attribute changes itself?

**Code where the problem occurs:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Point
{
    private:
        string _id;
        double _x;
        double _y;
    public:
        Point(string id="undefined", double x = 0.00f, double y = 0.00f)
        :_id(id), _x(x), _y(y){}
        ~Point(){}
    public:
        // Getters methods
        string getId() const          { return _id;}
        double getX()  const          { return _x; }
        double getY()  const          { return _y; }
        void   setId(string id)       { _id = id; }
        // Setters methods
        void   setX(double n = 0.00f) { _x = n; }
        void   setY(double n = 0.00f) { _y = n; }
        Point  prototype()            { return Point(_id, _x, _y); }
        Point  operator+ (const Point& p)
        {
            cout << "Operator + called, returning a new object" << endl;
            return Point
            (
                _id.append("+").append(p._id),
                _x+p._x,
                _y+p._y
            );

        }
        Point operator= (const Point& p)
        {
            cout << "Operator = called, returning a new object Point(p._id, p._x, p._y)" << endl;
            _id=p._id;
            _x=p._x;
            _y=p._y;
            return *this;
        }
};

int main()
{
    Point G("G",10.0f, 10.0f);
    Point H(G.prototype()); H.setId("H");
    Point R;
    R = G + H;
    cout << "object Point {id: " << G.getId() << ", x: " << G.getX() << ", y: " << G.getY() << "}" << endl;
    cout << "object Point {id: " << H.getId() << ", x: " << H.getX() << ", y: " << H.getY() << "}" << endl;
    cout << "object Point {id: " << R.getId() << ", x: " << R.getX() << ", y: " << R.getY() << "}" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line in the `operator+` overload:

```
_id.append("+").append(p._id),
```

You have to be very careful here, you are currently in an object (in your example this would be the `G` object).  `append` actually alters the local string, so your code is appending `+` then `p._id` then deep copying that to the returned value.

A quick fix is to change this to a temporary that holds what you need:

```
_id + "+" + p._id
```

To avoid problems like this in the future, you should declare operator overloads as a friend method so it's extremely clear what you're operating on.

```
friend Point  operator+ (const Point& lhs, const Point& rhs)
{
    cout << "Operator + called, returning a new object" << endl;
    return Point
    (
        lhs._id.append("+").append(rhs._id), //COMPILER ERROR!  We're modifying the const "lhs"!
        lhs._x+rhs._x,
        lhs._y+rhs._y
    );
}
```

So let's change this to:

```
friend Point  operator+ (const Point& lhs, const Point& rhs)
{
    cout << "Operator + called, returning a new object" << endl;
    return Point
    (
        lhs._id + "+" + rhs._id, // no longer modifying lhs -- all is well!
        lhs._x+rhs._x,
        lhs._y+rhs._y
    );
}
```

Comment: I appreciate those thorough details

Answer (score 2):

```
 Point  operator+ (const Point& p)
 {
     cout << "Operator + called, returning a new object" << endl;
     return Point
       (
          _id.append("+").append(p._id),    // HERE
          _x+p._x,
          _y+p._y
       );
}
```

In this line, you modify `_id` property of `this` object. As a rule of thumb, binary + operator should be a const member or - IMO cleaner - a static method taking two const reference arguments.

BTW, you can add strings in C++ by just applying + operator to them (`_id + "+" + p._id`).

Comment: Yes, the constant modifier solved the problem. Thanks for help and for the string operator usage.

Answer (score 2):

If you implement your binary arithmetic operators as members, you should consider making the operator a `const` member. This would catch the obvious modification in your implementation (the implementation is made out of line to avoid including unrelated code):

```
Point Point::operator+ (const Point& p) const
{
    cout << "Operator + called, returning a new object" << endl;
    return Point
        (
            _id.append("+").append(p._id),
            _x+p._x,
            _y+p._y
        );
}
```

The operation `_id.append("+")` actually operates on `this->_id`, i.e., the `_id` member of the left hand operand. Since you member operator isn't `const`, the compiler lets you do the modification. This is probably not what you intended to do. You probably rather wanted to write:

```
Point Point::operator+ (const Point& p) const
{
    cout << "Operator + called, returning a new object\n";
    return Point
        (
            _id + "+" + p._id,
            _x+p._x,
            _y+p._y
        );
}
```

... which creates a suitable temporary string with the desired value (I also replaced the [excessive use of `std::endl`](http://kuhllib.com/2012/01/14/stop-excessive-use-of-stdendl/)).

Comment: Yes the problem was with that const modifier. Great details described my problem.